# Creating a thread that stops when its own stop flag is set

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import threading
import time

class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""
    def __init__(self):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

    def func(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Hi")
            if self.stopped():
                break

t = StoppableThread()
t.target = t.func
t.start()
time.sleep(10)
t.stop()
```

This is an attempt by me to create a stoppable thread that will run its own method until it is stopped, at which point it should terminate (the `while` loop in `func` is broken out of). Unfortunately, nothing is printed by this code. My wish is for `"Hi"` to be printed every 0.5 seconds, for 10 seconds.

I also tried by defining the method as an external function with the thread passed in as an argument:

```
class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""
    def __init__(self):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

def func(thread):
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Hi")
        if thread.stopped():
            break

t = StoppableThread()
t.target = func
t.args = (t,) # passing in the thread as an argument to func so that func can check the stopped()-flag
t.start()
time.sleep(10)
t.stop()
```

This code yields the same result as the first example. What is wrong here? How can I get this to work?

Comment: It's `is_set`, not `it_set`.

Comment: Also, you're supposed to pass `target` as a constructor parameter to `Thread`, not set it as an attribute afterwards.

Comment: (Same with `args` - that needs to be a constructor parameter. Attributes are not equivalent to constructor parameters.)

Comment: Okay, but if I do that, how can I reference the thread itself?

Comment: `t = StoppableThread(target = t.func)` yields `NameError` because `t` is not yet defined.

Comment: Closure variable? Or override `run`?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm by no means a pro at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the help of @user2357112 's tips, I managed to come up with this solution (overriding `run()`):

```
import threading
import time

class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""
    def __init__(self):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

    def run(self):
        self.func()

    def func(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Hi")
            if self.stopped():
                break

t = StoppableThread()
t.start()
time.sleep(10)
t.stop()
```

I would still like to know how to do this with closures, if anyone could explain that.

Answer (score 0):

both of your examples set the target for the thread by doing `t.target = func` which is the incorrect way to specify the target.  You need to pass `target = func` to the constructor and then pass it to the call to super

The first case you would do `super(StoppableThread, self).__init__(target = self.func)` and the second case you would do

```
class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""
    def __init__(self, target): 
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__(target = target, args=(self._stop_event,))
```

Then `t = StoppableThread(target = func)` will work correctly.